# compare values in arrays and if any values match, increment values in first array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I've got this code to check two arrays for any matching values, and if any values do match I ++ everything in array1

I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this, since I feel like this is a lot of looping, and I'll eventually have 5 arrays i need to compare against each other

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
const array1 = [2, 9];

const array2 = [2, 5, 9];

function checkMatch(a, b) {
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (let e = 0; e < b.length; e++) {
      if (a[i] === b[e]) a[i]++;
    }
  }
  return a;
}

console.log(checkMatch(array1, array2))
```

Comment: please add the wanted result. btw, why do you have strings?

Comment: wanted result would be [3, 10]

Comment: why not `[3, 10]`?

Comment: sorry that was a typo, yes i edited my comment to [3, 10]

Comment: do you have only unique values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a `Set` and map the first array with the value plus the check for this value of the set.

```js
function checkMatch(a, b) {
    var values = new Set(b);
    return a.map(v => v + values.has(v));
}

console.log(checkMatch([2, 9], [2, 5, 9]));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that all arrays are sorted, then you can use the following approach -

### CODE -

```js
const array1 = [2, 9];

const array2 = [2, 5, 9];

function checkMatch(a, b) {
  let i = 0,
    j = 0;
  while (i < a.length && j < b.length) {
    if (a[i] === b[j]) {
      a[i]++;
      j++;
    } else if (a[i] < b[j]) {
      i++;
    } else j++;
  }
  return a;
}

console.log(checkMatch(array1, array2))
```

### Explanation -

The above approach will have a time complexity of `O(N+M)` while your could would have had a time complexity of `O(N*M)`.

In the above function, you are taking advantage of the fact that arrays are sorted. So when `a[i] < b[j]`, you know that you have to increment index i to get a value that can potentially be equal to or greater than `b[j]`. The same (but in the reverse way) is the case when `a[i] > b[j]`. So, this approach reduces the overall time-complexity of your code and would increases the overall efficiency.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `includes` method to check if all elements of a list (a) exits in all other arrays you need to compare. Then you can update the value in list (a)

```js
function checkMatch(a, b){
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(b.includes(a[i])){
            a[i]++;
        }
    }
  return a;
};

const array1 = [2, 9];
const array2 = [2, 5, 9];

console.log(checkMatch(array1, array2))
```

Comment: `includes()` is an linear search function. Time-complexity wise, your function is same as OP's question and has the time-compexity of O(N*M), where N & M are lengths of array1 and array2 respectively

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make use of `map` here:

```js
var array1 = [2, 9];
var array2 = [2, 5, 9];

var result = array1.map(n=>(array2.includes(n) ? n++ : n, n));

console.log(result);
```